# Grunt can load but not run a task

Tags: gruntjs

The packages are installed correctly but it can't run the default task. I have the latest version of grunt and npm. This is the output of `grunt default --verbose`

```
  Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-contrib-less" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/xxx/Git/x/web/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/xxx/Git/x/web/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/package.json...OK
Loading "less.js" tasks...OK
+ less
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

Running tasks: default

Running "default" task
Warning: Task "grunt-contrib-less" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: Be helpful to see the Gruntfile, but I'm guessing the key for the less task is: `grunt-contrib-less: {...` rather than simply `less: {...`. See the [examples](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less).

Comment: Yepp that was the problem! Post the comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task needs to be simply `less: {...` not `grunt-contrib-less: {...` like the [examples show](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less):

```
less: {
  development: {
    options: {
      paths: ["assets/css"]
    },
    files: {
      "path/to/result.css": "path/to/source.less"
    }
  }
}
```